# NHibernate and SQL query performance issue: stored procedure vs native SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, nhibernate, orm

I have a performance problem with the execution of a SQL query on NHibernate.

I tried to import the SQL code of a stored procedure in a SQL query, finding a large performance deterioration.

Here's an example of testing...

In my mapping file I have these two definitions:

```
<sql-query name="sp_Test1">
     exec MyStoredProcedure :Param1, :Param2, :Param3, :Param4
</sql-query>

<sql-query name="sp_Test2">
 <![CDATA[
     SELECT Field5 FROM MyTable 
     WHERE Field1 = :Param1 AND 
       Field2 = :Param2 AND 
       Field3 = :Param3 AND 
       Field4 = :Param4 
     ORDER BY Field5
 ]]>
</sql-query>
```

The native code of `sp_Test2` is exactly the same SQL code in the stored procedure.

Now if I run a test like this:

```
int count = 2500;

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int i=0; i<=count; i++) {
     //Execute query "sp_Test1"
}
sw.Stop();
//Print sw.ElapsedMilliseconds

sw.Reset();

sw.Start();
for (int i=0; i<=count; i++) {
     //Execute query "sp_Test2"
}
sw.Stop();
//Print sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

I get to the execution of `sp_Test1` a time of about 1 second, while for the execution of `sp_Test2` a time of about 20 seconds!

Can anyone tell me what is causing this degradation of performance? And how can I improve the performance of `sp_Test2`?

Note: I use NHibernate 2.1.2 for this test.

Thank you in advance for any useful information about.

Comment: I do not see a warmup in your test, I guess when you reverse your tests, you will have te opposite result.

Comment: I reversed the test but the results are the same...first run about 20 seconds (sp_Test2), second run about 1 second (sp_Test1)

Comment: How about installing a profiler and check it out? E.g. a free trial of [NH Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/NHProf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the code of the query "sp_Test2", writing it in this way:

```
<sql-query name="sp_Test2">
   <return-scalar column="Field5" type="Int32" />
   <![CDATA[
     DECLARE @Param1 nvarchar(30)
     DECLARE @Param2 nvarchar(30)
     DECLARE @Param3 nvarchar(30)
     DECLARE @Param4 smallint

     SET @Param1 = :Param1
     SET @Param2 = :Param2
     SET @Param3 = :Param3
     SET @Param4 = :Param4

     SELECT Field5 FROM MyTable WHERE Field1 = :Param1 AND Field2 = :Param2 AND Field3 = :Param3 AND Field4 = :Param4 ORDER BY Field5
   ]]>
</sql-query>
```

writing the query in this way, no more performance problems and have essentially the same execution time for stored procedures and sql native.